# JavaScript arrow function executes after code following up

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I am experiencing unexpected behaviour with arrow functions in JavaScript.

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
  this.user = context.loginHint!;
  console.log("Arrow function called");
});
console.log("Outside of Arrow Function");
```

When executing this code inside a React Component's constructor, the code block enclosed in the arrow function is the last one to be called. Even functions called after completions of the construction such as `componentDidMount()` are called earlier:

```
FetchFiles.tsx:21 Outside of Arrow Function
FetchFiles.tsx:28 Component did mount
FetchFiles.tsx:19 Arrow function called
```

I am wondering why the enclosed code block is not executed first. Is this the expected behaviour and if so, what am I missing here?

Comment: _"Is this the expected behaviour"_ - Yes. _"and if so, what am I missing here?"_ - `.getContext()` is asynchronous

Comment: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086)

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering why the enclosed code block is not executed first.

When it runs depends entirely on `getContext`. Apparently it calls the callback asynchronously, which is why the code in the callback runs later than the code following the `getContext` call.

Callbacks can be called synchronously (such as the one in array `sort` or `map`, or string `replace`) or asynchronously (such as the ones in promise `then` and `catch`, or `setTimeout`). Which it is depends entirely on what the callback is being supplied to.

In this case, it's [`microsoftTeams.getContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams?view=msteams-client-js-latest#getContext__context__Context_____void_) which does call the callback asynchronously, though sadly doesn't explicitly say that (in that small part of the documentation anyway). It it strongly implied by the fact that `getContext` accepts a callback rather than just returning the context. If it could be retrieved synchronously, you'd expect it to be supplied as a return value, not via a callback. (It'a also implied when that documentation says that `callback` is *"The callback to invoke when the xref:Context object is retrieved."*)

Comment: It is a shame that the term "callback" has become overloaded to mean both the `.map` style synchronous function and the async "something to be called later" :(

Comment: @Alnitak - I don't recall a time in my 30+ years of this stuff when it wasn't used for both of those things. It *would* be really nice to have separate terms, but...

Comment: Thanks, I am somewhat new to the syntax and wasn't aware of asynchron callbacks yet. Is there any way i which I can enforce it to run synchronously here? (Like with the `await` keyword)?